How to preserve input with double quotes in a run step (bash) in GitHub Actions?
This question is a GitHub Actions challenge, but afaik I should probably be solved with a run command (bash).
Background
I have a json file (see below) to automatically populate a DNS zone in my DigitalOcean environment.
dns-records.json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "key": "@",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "ttl": "600",
            "value": "<WEBSITE_NAME>.<HOSTING_DOMAIN>"
        },
        {
            "key": "www",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "ttl": "86400",
            "value": "@"
        },
        {
            "key": "@",
            "type": "CAA",
            "ttl": "86400",
            "value": "0 issue \"letsencrypt.org\""
        },
        {
            "key": "assets",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "ttl": "86400",
            "value": "<WEBSITE_NAME>.<DO_SPACES_REGION>.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com"
        }
    ]
}

In my GitHub Actions workflow, I use a matrix approach to trigger the doctl CLI command for the creation of the DNS records. Within the called creation job, the values are accessible as ${{ inputs.RECORD_DATA }}.
Challenges
I do want to alter the RECORD_DATA in a specific case: if the record type is CNAME and the record value is not '@' (a '@' key is fine!), then I have to add a dot ('.') to the end of the string - but only if the most right character isn't a dot yet.
Since GitHub Actions has no support for conditional / ternary operators (if-else statements), I use a bash run step for the if-else.
Pseudo code:
RECORD_DATA_LAST_CHAR="insert magic here?"
if [ RECORD_TYPE == 'CNAME' && $RECORD != '@' && $RECORD_DATA_LAST_CHAR != '.' ]; then
  echo "MANIPULATED_RECORD_DATA=$RECORD_DATA." >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
ese
  echo "MANIPULATED_RECORD_DATA=$RECORD_DATA" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
fi

PS1: The echo to $GITHUB_OUTPUT is the GHA way to reuse variables in later workflow steps.
PS2: I usually use a step-level environment variable for the input, so bash can use this instead of the GHA ${{}}.
env:
  RECORD_DATA: ${{ inputs.RECORD_DATA }}

My first question: how can I get the last character of ${{ inputs.RECORD_DATA }} in my bash run command, in such a way that is also works on the CAA example in the json with both spaces and double quotes in it?
My second question: I have to use the $MANIPULATED_RECORD_DATA as input for the doctl command to create the DNS record. How can I preserve the original escaped quotes from the letsencrypt CAA example record, so $MANIPULATED_RECORD_DATA is passed including these quotes?
Error results
Failing example without ending dot.
doctl compute domain records create domain.name \
    --record-type CNAME \
    --record-name @ \
    --record-data "hostname.domain.name" \
    --record-ttl 600 \
    --verbose=false

shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/domain.name/records: 422 (request "629564e1-160e-4f9b-bd26-37e441df0ca7") Data needs to end with a dot (.)
Failing doctl example when in-string quotes aren't escaped.
doctl compute domain records create domain.name \
    --record-type CAA \
    --record-name @ \
    --record-data "0 issue "letsencrypt.org"" \
    --record-ttl 86400 \
    --verbose=false

shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/domain.name/records: 422 (request "173475ec-31d1-41f7-9ae6-aa9424f4a4bd") Tag can't be empty, Tag can't be empty, Tag can't be blank, Tag must be issue, issuewild and or iodef
Failed try & error attempts
I found this post about how a var can be made available, including the quotes, to a child process. But I failed to include this in a GHA run command.
export var
bash -c 'echo "$var"'

I can't get RECORD_DATA_LAST_CHAR=${RECORD_DATA: -1} to work but perhaps this is related to quote issues as well? I've tried parameter expansion and sed but somehow fail to use them properly combined with echo.
Any help to 'unstuck' me would be highly appreciated. I'm quite a newbie to GHA and not a bash pro either.
Note: I'm aware that simply adding the dots in the json file with records would eliminate my issue. I'd like to avoid that hard requirement tho.

You can form ternary expressions like this ${{ condition && true || false }}. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example.

tl;dr You should give jq a try. It's a much better tool to manipulate JSON. See https://jqlang.github.io/jq/.

@Azeem thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I've been able to reduce bash complexity by moving vars and expressions to env: first.

The digitalocean API doesn't handle CAA records as a single record_data string, but has specific fields for tags and flags (only the authority goes to the data field). This basically solved my issue.
